# Android no permission to read from phonebook

Tags: android, android-studio, permissions

I'm new on android. I want to make a function that check if I already have a phone number in my phonebook.
I added read contacts permission on my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

I can't get the permission to read the contacts and my app crash every time.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you have to check if you have a permission or not before you doing something from the dangerous permissions list

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR);
```

If it returns that your app is not granted then you need to ask for it in the runtime.

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
```

So, put the code above after your first "if" statement in "else" block.

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: permissionCheck is instead hasPermission??? and MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS has an error

Comment: @AlexTech it is better if you check your permissions using ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission() and MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS could be any int you want. You will need it to handle request permissions if you will need to.
Just make MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 10